# dynamically set key and value for struct

Tags: go

my problem is, i have key that will having non-fixed value, like in python, we can do :

```
dict_ = {}
data_ = [{"name": "roy", "text": "yay i got a gift"},{"name": "dep", "text": "my mum gimme a gift"},{"name": "roy", "text": "another gift from my fan"}]
for data in data_:
    key = data["name"]
    if key in dict_:
        dict_[key] += 1 // add more 1 if key already in dict_
    else:
        dict_[key] = 1 // set dict key with starting value 1
```

i'm trying do that with golang, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equivalent Go code:

```
dict_ := make(map[string]int)
data_ := []map[string]string{{"name": "roy", "text": "yay i got a gift"}, {"name": "dep", "text": "my mum gimme a gift"}, {"name": "roy", "text": "another gift from my fan"}}

for _, data := range data_ {
    key := data["name"]
    dict_[key]++ // default value is always the zero value
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PtJwS2quoBp)

Comment: thank you !, i need to learn more about ```make``` & ```map```